# Excel filter questions

Tags: excel, filtering

I need to know how to do the following filters:

- Filter a date column to show weekend dates only
- Filter a date column to show the first and last day of a month only
- Filter a number column to show round numbers only (e.g. include show 12 but filter out things like 12.12)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing VBA? If not, this might be better directed at SuperUser.

Comment: Not, just want to use Excel formulas. Who's SuperUser?

Comment: SuperUser.com is another site in SO family. Questions that deal with application use rather than programming should be directed there.

Comment: I am not clear whether Excel formula count as application configuration or programming. They feel like programming (or at least scripting).

Comment: @Jonty, did you find my answer helpful? You didn't accept it or upvote i, and there is no other response.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some formulae that will be true for the rows you want.

Copy these into another column, and you can then filter the rows based on the truth value of the column.

Formulae assume the value to be examined is stored in A1.

Is a weekend:

```
 =WEEKDAY(A1,3)>=5
```

Is the first or last day of the month:

```
=OR(DAY(A1)=1,DAY(A1+1)=1)
```

Is a round number:

```
 =A1=INT(A1)
```